# Open-Source Document Circulation & Workflow Web-Based System

Tags: php, web-applications

I am looking for an open-source document circulation and workflow web-based system to add it in the website that I am developing now.

I searched a little bit in Google and I found the following interesting system:
http://www.cuteflow.org/index.html

But the problem with that system is no one can create workflow or document circulation except the Admin. What I want is such a system that makes any user creates a document to decide whether create workflow or not.

So do you know any web-based system that I can use it in the website? Any suggestion or feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe take a look at the community edition of [KnowledgeTree](http://www.knowledgetree.org/).